# Writing result in TXT file is in HEXA code? (32 bit assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86, hex, 32-bit

I cant seem to figure out why does my two procedures that open and write/export the result of greatest common divider into txt called FileName in HEXA !

When I open the TXT there is something written, when i open the TXT in hexaeditor the result is good, any ideas why ? I moved the result from eax to pomGCD.

```
PomGCD DB 10 dup(?)
MenoSub DB 'GCD.txt',0 
FileHandle DD ?
ByteNumber DD ?
LetterNumber DD 1


openFile PROC                                       ; 2 procedures for opening and writing
    push NULL   
    push FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL  
    push CREATE_ALWAYS
    push NULL
    push 0
    push GENERIC_WRITE
    push offset FileName
    call CreateFileA 
    mov FileHandle,eax
    ret
openFile ENDP

writeFile PROC
    push NULL
    push offset ByteNumber
    push LetterNumber
    push offset pomGCD
    push FileHandle
    call WriteFile
    ; close file
    push FileHandle
    call CloseHandle
    ret
writeFile ENDP
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you convert the result into ASCII-Characters before saving it into the TXT-file? Otherwise it is still a binary number. That could explain, why you can read it with a hex-editor.